# doubt computing ML estimate

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, maximum-likelihood

I was going through a solved example on https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_3_comparison_to_ML_estimation.php for computation of ML estimate of a distribution.

In this article, they state $Y = X + W$ where $W \sim N(0, \sigma_w^2)$ and independent of X. The authors then express $Y|X$ as $Y|X = x  \sim  N(x,\sigma_{W}^2)$

Could anyone please explain this step ?

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead.

Comment: It is not good notation. They are saying the conditional distribution of Y given X is normal with mean X and variance from the noise term, W. I would write $Y|X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(x, \sigma_w^2\right)$. This is because X is known and W is an independent noise term, and

Comment: PLease change the title of your question as this has nothing to do with maximum likelihood or machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a fixed real number and $W\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_W)$, then
$$Y=x+W\sim\mathcal{N}(x,\sigma^2_W)$$Now, if $X$ is a random variable and the *conditional* distribution of $W$ *given* $X$ is $W|X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_W)$, then
$$Y=X+W|X\sim\mathcal{N}(X,\sigma^2_W)$$
Given a realisation of $X$, $x$, the conditional model operates as if $X$ is not random but replaced by its realisation.

Comment: why is there a "nearly equal sign"? are we assuming that the standard deviation for noise is less than that of the signal

Comment: i thought that the tilde was denoting 'nearly equal' meaning. Anyways, could you explain a bit more about this tilde notation that you mentioned in the comments. I mean, "rv X on the left is distributed from the distribution F on the right" - does it mean that X is dependent on F. kindly elaborate on this notation and its interpretation

Comment: sorry, I fear I cannot get into such tutoring, please invest some time in reading a probability textbook.